# is solana benifiting with solana virtual machine

Tags: blockchain, ether, evm, bridge, solana

What is the meaning for a blockchain of not having evm or vm compatibility? What benefits solana will get of now having svm?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning for a blockchain of not having evm compatibility is that this allows innovation and experiment that are not constrained to the limitations of evm. These limitations include stiffness of the evm's bytecode language and native functionality, as well as lack of robustness of the design of the evm. The benefits of solana of now having svm is using rust programming language, parallel transaction execution, high throughput, and faster finality.

See: https://shardeum.org/blog/evm-vs-non-evm/